# Intelij maven window not removing dependencies that were removed from pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Throughout the development, I've added a few dependencies of submodules and then removed them. Part of the dependencies were added via the pom.xml and part of them via the Project Structure/Modules window.
The addition is reflected immediately on the maven tool window on the right.
But, when I remove those dependencies, they stay in the maven window tool and are marked in red - since I totally removed the submodules from the project - and they actually do not exist.

[image: maven tool window]

I've tried to remove those dependencies through Project structure > Modules > Dependencies,
but I keep seeing on the window bottom the message:
"Module 'xx' is imported from maven. Any changes made in its configuration may be lost after reporting":
[image: Project structure/Modules/dependencies]

I've already tried Invalidate Caches/Restart.
Reload project.

Why is it happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: This might solve it for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64661460/how-can-i-remove-a-dependency-from-intellij-which-i-added-through-pom-xml

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I Have already seen this question and tried it, but no help.